# Change css files loaded order in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I want to write some new css style in `custom.css.scss` to overwrite some style.

But I found I couldn't over-write  the external files under `/vendor/themes`

How could I make high priority for my `custom.css.scss`, Thanks

### Application.css

```
 *= require news
 *= require photo
 *= require_self
 *= require custom
```

### Application.rb

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/themes"
```

Answer (score 3):

In the rails doc for [Assets Pipeline:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

> *Besides the standard assets/* paths, additional (fully qualified) paths can be added to the *pipeline in config/application.rb. For example:*

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("lib", "videoplayer", "flash")
```

> *Paths are traversed in the order they occur in the search path. By default, this means the files in app/assets take precedence, and will mask corresponding paths in lib and vendor.*
>
> *It is important to note that files you want to reference outside a manifest must be added to the precompile array or they will not be available in the production environment.*

So your custom css is actually overriding the vendor css. But maybe there is some rules in the vendor that have greater css prority (more css selectors for example) and that's why they don't get overridden.